# How to drill an HTML document and find specific controls buried into it?

Tags: html, jquery, element

I have worked lately with web grids and sometimes I need to locate some controls by the id they were rendered, where something like mycheckbox ends being identified in the documented as something like ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl04_mycheckbox.

Currently I have done this manually digging into the elements with Chrome debugger. While it works it's a tedious task and it still forces me to tweak my code every time I need to add or remove a column in the grid. Also depending on the structure of the document the location of the control may change dramatically.

Basically what I do, after to find where the name of the control is, is something similar to this:

```
var grid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
mychk = grid._element.children[0].children[4].children[0].children[7].children[0].firstChild.id; // mycheckbox
```

I want to write a function to automatize this task, something like **FindMyControl("mycheckbox")** which would dig the whole document until find an id containing the basic name of the control.

I'd like to know what would be the best approach to do this and if there is some JQuery function which helps to achieve this result.

Comment: jQuery has the ability to find elements if an attribute ends with something specific. **$('[id$=”mycheckbox”]')** obviously, you will need to feed it a parent also to search within. https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: You've inconveniently left out any example of your html, but if you're saying the elements you need have an ID attribute whose value is known ahead of time, all you need is to call `document.getElementById()` with that value.

Comment: Hey @Daniel Beck... it's not that simple. Please read my explanation and you will understand. Your "solution" only works when you have unique controls. By the other hand when they are used as columns of a RadGrid, the instances of this control in the rows of the grid are rendered as "ctl100_etc".